# Error "The maximum rows allowed in a worksheet may have been exceeded (Exception 312)"

Tags: excel

I'm retrieving data from Showcase and placing it on an Excel table but every time this data exceeds the number of rows that fits in one page of Excel it throws the following error and the table does not resize. The table resizes when the number of rows of the table is bigger than the number of rows retrieved from Showcase but even in this case it is still throwing the error.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Big plus for showing an error message that uses "**may have been**" in its description of events. :D It seems almost apologetic.

Comment: This is ShowCase http://www.helpsystems.com/showcase/showcase and I have its add-in for excel. The number of rows depends on how many rows are retrieved from showcase. Sorry about my english.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that Showcase creates a linked table?